Failed to set parameters using the service /turtlesim/set_parameters of the SetParameters type
I tried to use the service /turtlesim/set_parameters [rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters] to set the background of the turtlesim GUI. But I cannot get right the form of the request.
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rcl_interfaces.srv import SetParameters

class SetParametersClient(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('set_parameters_client')
        self.client = self.create_client(SetParameters, '/turtlesim/set_parameters')
        while not self.client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('Service not available, waiting again...')

    def set_parameters(self, parameters):
        request = SetParameters.Request()
        request.parameters = parameters


        future = self.client.call_async(request)
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)

        if future.result() is not None:
            self.get_logger().info('Parameters set successfully')
        else:
            self.get_logger().error('Failed to set parameters')

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    set_params_client = SetParametersClient()

    # Define the parameters to be set
    parameters = [
            {
                "name": "background_r",
                "value": 255.0  # Set red component to maximum value
            },
            {
                "name": "background_g",
                "value": 0.0    # Set green component to zero
            },
            {
                "name": "background_b",
                "value": 0.0    # Set blue component to zero
            }
        ]
    # Call the set_parameters service
    set_params_client.set_parameters(parameters)

    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

when I run the script, I got the following error message:
AssertionError: The 'parameters' field must be a set or sequence and each value of type 'Parameter'

How should I define the parameters to be set?

I  found the solution by accident, but I cannot know why it is so. Below is the code
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rcl_interfaces.srv import SetParameters
from rcl_interfaces.msg import ParameterValue
from rcl_interfaces.msg import Parameter
class SetParametersClient(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('set_parameters_client')
        self.client = self.create_client(SetParameters, '/turtlesim/set_parameters')
        while not self.client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('Service not available, waiting again...')

    def set_parameters(self, parameters):
        request = SetParameters.Request()
        request.parameters = parameters


        future = self.client.call_async(request)
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)

        if future.result() is not None:
            self.get_logger().info('Parameters set successfully')
        else:
            self.get_logger().error('Failed to set parameters')

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    set_params_client = SetParametersClient()

    # Define the parameters to be set
    parameters = [Parameter(name='background_r', value=ParameterValue(type=2, bool_value=False, integer_value=255, double_value=0.0, string_value='', byte_array_value=[], bool_array_value=[], integer_array_value=[], double_array_value=[], string_array_value=[]))]
    # Call the set_parameters service
    set_params_client.set_parameters(parameters)

    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


If you compare your original code with this code, then you should be able to see what has changed and (hopefully) why it now works

@Greenonline You are right. Maybe it is because I do not know the defination of parameters, or my poor grasp of the programming language python is to be blame.
